# searchbar is distorted after iOS update

Tags: ios, swift

I have a SearchBar with the following constraints:
Leadingspace and proportional width to Superview, Height Equals 60 and Align Top to another View.
to get rid of the background I set `barTintColor = UIColor.clear` and `backgroundimage = UIImage()`
it used to look like this:

[image]

but now I updated iOS on my phone and I got only a black rectangle.
if I delete the to lines above it looks like this(the bottom left corner is from another view):

[image]

How can I get it to look like before?

Comment: Try this code didlayoutsubviews method

Comment: Please share the iOS version where it still worked and the iOS version that results in the wrong image. Does the same thing happen on the simulator?

Comment: @koen i'm not sure what exaxt version i had, it was 12.* Now i have 13.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You also can make your own SearchBar.

using UIView and UITextField. So using these control you can design as per your design easily.

[image]